# Nativescript: how to collapse view when software keyboard is shown on iOS?

Tags: ios, nativescript

I have a chat screen and when the textfield is focused iOS soft keyboard appear. It overlaps the view and the textfield and the send button get hidden. Is there a way to collapse the view in the way that outer GridView height would be equal GridView height - soft keyboard height? This will allow to all elements to be visible.

Here is my xml layout:

```
<Page id="main"
  xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
  navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo">

        <GridLayout rows="auto, auto, *, auto, auto">

            <!-- Title -->
            <Label text="{{ L('chat', 'title') }}" class="title title-bar" row="0"/>
            <StackLayout class="line" row="1"/>

            <ListView id="messagesList" items="{{ messages }}" separatorColor="transparent" row="2">
                <ListView.itemTemplate>
                    <GridLayout columns="auto * auto" class="chat-item">
                        <Label text="{{ getChatUserName(isUser) }}" class="chat-avatar"
                               col="{{ isUser ? '2' : '0' }}"/>
                        <Label text="{{ message }}"
                               class="{{ isUser ? 'chat-message chat-message-user' : 'chat-message' }}"
                               textWrap="true" col="1"/>
                    </GridLayout>
                </ListView.itemTemplate>
            </ListView>

            <TextField text="{{ messageToSend }}" hint="{{ L('chat', 'text_hint') }}" row="3" returnPress="{{ send }}"/>
            <Button text="{{ L('chat', 'send_btn') }}" class="footer-grey-button-wrapper footer-grey-button"
                    tap="{{ send }}" col="0" row="4"/>

        </GridLayout>

</Page>
```

Comment: Use the plugin in the answer. iOS doesnt handle moving view components around by default so that's why the native lib exists. Android handles this with a setting in your app manifest, which should be enabled by default to adjust the view when soft keyboard is shown

Comment: Well, I installed the plugin, but how do I use it? For now textfield and button get still hidden when the soft keyboard is slide up.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this plugin which is made for iOS to prevent keyboard from overlapping the view

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager